# How to log lazily with ASP.NET Core logging?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-logging

Suppose a scenario like this:

```
[Route("api/test")]
public class TestController
{
    private readonly ILogger<TestController> logger;

    public TestController(ILogger<TestController> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public void Put(Guid id, [FromBody]FooModel model)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"Putting {id}");
        logger.LogTrace("Putting model {0}", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
        try
        {
            // Omitted: actual PUT operation.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError("Exception {0}", ex);
        }
    }
}

public class FooModel 
{ 
    string Bar { get; set; } 
}
```

In this scenario, the `LogInformation` call will trigger a `string.Format` call, and even worse, the `LogTrace` line will trigger **a `SerializeObject` call, regardless of the `LogLevel`**. That seems rather wasteful.

Is there a place in the Logging API that allows for a more lazy approach? The only workaround I can think of is overriding `ToString` on model to create a very verbose representation, and skip on using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` as a tool.

Comment: Here is an article that uses `IsEnabled` http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/11/19/asp-net-5-why-use-ilogger-isenabled/

Comment: If this isn't what you are looking for, do you mean that you still want the logging to occur but not cause the main thread to get delayed?

Comment: Ah, no, the article as well as @meziantou's answer seem to be what I want, though I'm still pondering how I could prevent having to repeat that everywhere. Basically I was looking for e.g. something in the API that would allow me to combine `Logger.IsEnabled(...)` and the `Logger.LogTrace(...)` call.

Comment: Create your own implementation of ILogger. Then, setup the different conditions in there as a generic and default case. It's not too tedious. You just have to be okay with with a generic style of logging for the most part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ILogger` interface provides the `IsEnabled` method:

```
if (logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Information))
{
    logger.LogInformation($"Putting {id}");
}

if (logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Trace))
{
    logger.LogTrace("Putting model {0}", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
}
```

You'll find the default implementation on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging/src/Logger.cs#L53